# How to access a string array with a string variable? Javascript

Tags: javascript

I need access to `h_00` with other variable, any idea?

```
var json = '{"h_00":[["bus",28,"F"],["bus",71,"M"],["car",16,"M"]]}';
var arr_data = jQuery.parseJSON(json);

var access = "h_00";

alert(arr_data.access[0]);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamic object property name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamic-object-property-name)

Comment: FYI, that's not a string array, that's an **object**.

Comment: `access[0]` will translate to `"h"` in your case. `arr_data.access[0]` will try to access a method or variable `access` under `arr_data` which does not exist.

Comment: @Sumurai8: You are right that `access[0]` would return `'h'` but `arr_data.access[0]` would throw an error because `arr_data.access` is `undefined`. `access` in `arr_data.access` has nothing to do with the variable `access`.

Comment: @FelixKling Hmmm true, I was not complete enough in that comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators#Bracket_notation):

```
arr_data[access][0]; // ["bus", 28, "F"]
```

Also that is not called a string array. It is an [object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects).

Answer (score 0):

`alert(arr_data[access][0]);` should work for you...

Answer (score 0):

If you that standard JSON parser it will accomplish your task:

```
var json = '{"h_00":[["bus",28,"F"],["bus",71,"M"],["car",16,"M"]]}';
var obj = JSON.parse(json);
```

You can simply access your property:

```
obj.h_00
```

And
    obj.h_00[0]

Will output:

```
["bus", 28, "F"]
```

Comment: *"I need access to h_00 with other variable"* probably means that the property name is stored in a variable. Considering that the OP tried `arr_data.access`, I think we can assume that they know about dot notation.